# MySQL Workbench - connect for server configured as shared-memory mode

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and configured it to `shared-memory` mode. Evetything is fine, but I have also installed Workbench program but I can't connect to the service - I get the `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)` error. So, how to connect to that server using localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

## SOLVED

I had to add to the MySQL Server `my.ini` config file `enable-named-pipe` option, and then in the Workbench, create New Connection and select `Connection Method` to `Local Socket/Pipe`. I have left the `Socket/Pipe path` textbox blank

Comment: Accept this answer.